# Error when installing react-router-dom npm install issue

Tags: reactjs

I have node v12.16.2, and npm 7.16.0 running on Mac OS Big Sur 11.5.1.

I just installed a npx react project, with:

```
npx create-react-app frontend
```

and this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I try to add:

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

I get the following error:

> npm WARN tarball tarball data for
> hoist-non-react-statics@https://registry.npmjs.org/hoist-non-react-statics/-/hoist-non-react-statics-3.3.2.tgz
> (sha512-/gGivxi8JPKWNm/W0jSmzcMPpfpPLc3dY/6GxhX2hQ9iGj3aDfklV4ET7NjKpSinLpJ5vafa9iiGIEZg10SfBw==)
> seems to be corrupted. Trying again. npm WARN tarball tarball data for
> hoist-non-react-statics@https://registry.npmjs.org/hoist-non-react-statics/-/hoist-non-react-statics-3.3.2.tgz
> (sha512-/gGivxi8JPKWNm/W0jSmzcMPpfpPLc3dY/6GxhX2hQ9iGj3aDfklV4ET7NjKpSinLpJ5vafa9iiGIEZg10SfBw==)
> seems to be corrupted. Trying again. npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR!
> syscall lstat npm ERR! path
> /Users/sven/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/fe/01/a2bf18bc24f296366fd6d234a6cdc30fa5fa4f2dcddd63fe86c615f6850f621a3dda0df925578113ecd8caa528a72e9279bda7daf62886204660d7449f07
> npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory,
> lstat
> '/Users/sven/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/fe/01/a2bf18bc24f296366fd6d234a6cdc30fa5fa4f2dcddd63fe86c615f6850f621a3dda0df925578113ecd8caa528a72e9279bda7daf62886204660d7449f07'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/sven/.npm/_logs/2021-08-02T09_21_43_877Z-debug.log

What could this issue be about: incompatible versions of node or npm for npx create react app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- npm cache clean
- npm i react-router-dom --save

Comment: This worked out, thanks :)
But do you know why this issue occurs in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which directory you are running the second command from but you need to be in the project directory (same dir as package.json). `cd frontend` before the second command.

Comment: Actuallly I am doing npm i react-router-dom in the frontend directory